# /bin/sh -c /install/install_pi_python3_toolchain.sh returned a non zero code: 100

Tags: python-3.x, docker, apt

I am trying to install Tensorflow on Raspberry PI 3B using Docker for Python3 by following [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_rpi). After installing Docker and doing `git checkout r.10`, when I run the docker command, it gives the following error

[image].

The shell file `install_pi_python3_toolchain.sh` looks like this

```
dpkg --add-architecture armhf
echo 'deb [arch=armhf] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ trusty main restricted universe multiverse' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/armhf.list
echo 'deb [arch=armhf] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/armhf.list
echo 'deb [arch=armhf] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/armhf.list
echo 'deb [arch=armhf] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/armhf.list
sed -i 's#deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/#deb [arch=amd64] http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/#g' /etc/apt/sources.list
apt-get -y update
apt-get install -y libpython3-all-dev:armhf
echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://storage.googleapis.com/bazel-apt stable jdk1.8" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/bazel.list
wget http://bazel.build/bazel-release.pub.gpg | sudo -E apt-key add -
apt-get -y update
#rm -rf /usr/local/bin/bazel
#apt-get install -y bazel python3 python3-numpy python3-dev python3-pip
```

I added `-y` after going though some other answers.

Comment: Since this isn't programming related, you should ask this in either https://superuser.com or https://askubuntu.com

Comment: I am not sure why you think that it isn't a programming related question !!

Comment: Because your question starts with "I am trying to install Tensorflow...". Where's the programming here?